# Working with lists in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have two non-unique lists of values, such as

```
["a", "b", "a", "c"]
```

and

```
 ["a", "b", "b", "f"]
```

I want to find which elements of the second list do not appear in the first.

I could code this by hand, but would prefer to use built-in functions. I can't figure out how because I keep bumping into the hashable / unhashable barrier.

Comment: If your barrier is that your values are unhashable, then tell us what your values are so we can help you work around it.

Comment: I understand now. I thought the error message referred to the collective objects, not their members. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

In this case it would be

```
set(second_list) - set(first_list)
```

because strings are hashable and you can put them in sets. If you have non-hashable values then tell us what they are and we can probably come up with a workaround. For example:

- You can convert a list to a tuple using `tuple(the_list)`, can back using `list(the_tuple)`.
- You can convert a set to a tuple using `tuple(the_set)`, can back using `set(the_tuple)`.
- You can convert a nested list to a nested tuple using `tuple(map(tuple, the_list))` and back using `list(map(list, the_tuple))`.
- You can convert a dictionary to a nested tuple using `tuple(the_dict.items())` and back using `dict(the_tuple)`.

Comment: Tried this and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

[x for x in ListB if x not in ListB]

I think this is a pretty fast way you can use.